# How would I go about setting a minimum timeout function on a loading template

Tags: javascript, meteor, timeout, preload

I want to have a loading template, with a minimum load time no matter if the data is ready. So basically run loading template for 1 second, even if the template and subscriptions are loaded?

My Router code below.

```
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'layout',
  loadingTemplate: 'loading',
  waitOn: function() { return Meteor.subscribe('contacts'); }
});

Router.map(function() {
  this.route('acorn', {path: '/'});
});

Router.onBeforeAction('loading');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could accomplish this by wrapping the call to `Meteor.subscribe` and writing passthroughs for the `ready` and `stop` methods of the subscription instance. Your version of `ready` would only return true after a second has passed and the wrapped subscription is ready.

Your `waitOn` method might look like:

```
waitOn: function() {
    var sub = Meteor.subscribe("contacts");
    var dep = new Tracker.Dependency();
    var isSubReady = false;
    var hasWaitTimePassed = false;

    Meteor.setTimeout(function() {
        hasWaitTimePassed = true;
        dep.changed();
    }, 1000);

    Tracker.autorun(function() {
        isSubReady = sub.ready();
        dep.changed();
    });

    return {
        ready: function() {
            dep.depend();
            return hasWaitTimePassed && isSubReady;
        },
        stop: function() {
            sub.stop();
        }
    };
}
```

Of course, if you want to use this in many places, you'd want to wrap all the logic up into a reusable function so you could do something like:

```
waitOn: function() {
    return subscribeWithDelay("contacts", 1000);
}
```